# Display json data in row with ListView

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to display the data in the activity into the ListView
below is the image
[image]

if this is the code I have

```
    FutureBuilder(
      future: UserController.getActivity(_selectedUser),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
           return Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                   Expanded

(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                       itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                       itemBuilder: (context, position){
                        var item = snapshot.data.elementAt(position);
                        return Text(item[0]["activity "]);
                       }
                   ),
                )
            ],
           );
         }

         return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
      },
   ),
```

here is the code for api.dart

```
   static getCompany() async {
    return await Http.get("user/getCompany");
  }
```

this is the controller code to the database

```
public function GetCompany() {
        $sql = "SELECT 
        clients.companies.name
      FROM
        clients.companies";
        $parameter = [];

        return $this->queryArray($sql, $parameter);
    }
```

and queryArray from library.php

```
protected function queryArray($sql, $parameter){
        try {
            $stmt = $this->query($sql, $parameter);
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return array();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of UI how it looks like in row?

Comment: I mean only a list of sequential data

Comment: Have you fetched the JSON from the server?

Comment: if i try print(snapshot.data.toString()). the data will appear in the form of json. and if it displays data based on ["activity"] it doesn't appear

Comment: I have added a code snippet in the comment, Please check and let me know if it not helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, how I am fetching data from firebase

```
Future<void> _getCarList() async {
    _list.clear();

    setState(() {
      isApiInExecution = true;
    });

    await _driveListRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        isApiInExecution = false;
      });

      if (snapshot == null || snapshot.value == null) {
        return;
      }
      print(' 11 Connected to second database and read ${snapshot.value}');
//      HashMap<String, String> _values = snapshot.value;
      snapshot.value.forEach((key, _vehicleModel) {
        VehicleModel vehicleModel = VehicleModel(
            rego: (_vehicleModel['rego'] != null ? _vehicleModel['rego'] : ""),
            state:
                (_vehicleModel['state'] != null ? _vehicleModel['state'] : ""),
            vin: (_vehicleModel['vin'] != null ? _vehicleModel['vin'] : ""),
            year: (_vehicleModel['year'] != null ? _vehicleModel['year'] : ""),
            make: (_vehicleModel['make'] != null ? _vehicleModel['make'] : ""),
            model:
                (_vehicleModel['model'] != null ? _vehicleModel['model'] : ""),
            colour: (_vehicleModel['colour'] != null
                ? _vehicleModel['colour']
                : ""));

        _list.add(vehicleModel);
      });
    }).then((onError) {
      if (onError == null) {
        return;
      }
      print('On Error Connected to second database and read $onError');
    });
  }
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you!! but if I use a controller with php and  API dart, is the same way?

Comment: Yes it almost same just need to replace snapshot with the api response

Comment: emm.. I use a web service that contains a php controller and dart fire.. I really don't understand. help me please!!

Comment: I need to check it in your code if possible share it with me

Comment: which part is changed?

Comment: controller and api file?

Comment: Yes I need both